# Several lines of code stop program from running?

Tags: arduino-mega

After a lot of help from you guys (huge thanks) Ive completed my code and gone to test it. unfortunately though one line of code `weight = (tip_read.get_units());` stops anything from happening and on the mode one, two or three sub programs it freezes somewhere in there. Any and all help and advice is welcome as Ive been trying to fix this all day and got literly nowhere.

```
#include <HX711.h>

#include <Wire.h>  // IC2 communication

#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>  //LCD
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd = LiquidCrystal_I2C(0x27, 20, 4); // Change to (0x27,16,2) for 16x2 LCD.

int max_load;
int interval;
int max_load_prev;
int interval_prev;
int mode;
float handle_weight;
float tip_weight;
int stop1;
int mode_previous;
int interval_sum;

int mode1 = 53;
int mode2 = 51;
int mode3 = 49;
int start1 = 39;
int start2 = 37;
int increment = 47;
float potentiometer1 = A0;
float potentiometer2 = A1;
int tare_1 = 45;
int tare_2 = 43;


//stepper motor controller
int stepPin = 12;
int dirPin = 13;

#
//sensor readings
  HX711 tip_read;
  HX711 handle_read;
  #define DOUT_tip  4
  #define DOUT_handle  6
  #define CLK_tip  3
  #define CLK_handle  5

  //saving to array//
  float data_storage_array[400][3];
  
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  
  lcd.init();
  lcd.backlight();



  pinMode(mode1, INPUT);
  pinMode(mode2, INPUT);
  pinMode(mode3, INPUT);
  pinMode(start1, INPUT);
  pinMode(start2, INPUT);
  pinMode(increment, INPUT);
  pinMode(stop1, INPUT);
  pinMode(potentiometer1, INPUT);
  pinMode(potentiometer2, INPUT);

  //sesnor readings

  
  tip_read.begin(DOUT_tip, CLK_tip);
  tip_read.set_scale(194);// change to calibration factor

  handle_read.begin(CLK_tip,CLK_handle);
  handle_read.set_scale(43.5);// change to calibration factor

  pinMode(tare_1, INPUT);
  pinMode(tare_2, INPUT);

  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(stepPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dirPin, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  mode_previous = 0;
  interval = 25;
  max_load_prev = 0;
  interval_prev = 0;
  interval_sum = 0;
  while (digitalRead(start1) == 0){
    if (digitalRead(mode1) == 1){
      mode = 1;
    }
    if (digitalRead(mode2) == 1){
      mode = 2;
    }
    if (digitalRead(mode3) == 1){
      mode = 3;
    }
    if (mode_previous != mode){
      Display_mode_set_up(mode);
      mode_previous = mode;
    }
    if (digitalRead(increment) == 1){
      delay(500);
      if (interval >= 1000){
         interval = 25;
      }
      else if (interval < 1000){
        interval = interval + 25;
      }
    }
    max_load = max_load_reading();
    if (max_load_prev != max_load or interval_prev != interval){
      Display_value_set_up(max_load, interval, mode);
      max_load_prev = max_load;
      interval_prev = interval;
    }
   Display_output(handle_weight, tip_weight);
   tare_one();
  }
  if (mode == 1){
    mode_one(max_load, tip_weight);
  }
  else if (mode == 2){
    mode_two(max_load, interval, handle_weight);
  }
  else if (mode ==3){
    mode_three(max_load, interval, handle_weight);
  }
  Pause_stop();

}



//---SUB ROUTINES---


void mode_one(int max_load, float tip_weight){
  tip_weight = read_tip();
  while (tip_weight < max_load){
    tip_weight = read_tip();
    turn_motor();
    Pause_stop();
    Display_output(handle_weight, tip_weight);
  }
}

void mode_two(int max_load, int interval, float handle_weight){
  int aim_value;
  aim_value = 0 + interval;
  tip_weight = read_tip();
  while (tip_weight < max_load){
    while (tip_weight < aim_value){
      turn_motor();
      Pause_stop();
      Display_output(handle_weight, tip_weight);
      tip_weight = read_tip();
    }
    save_to_array(interval_sum);
    aim_value = aim_value + interval;
    while (digitalRead(start2) == 0){
      delay(1);
    }
  }
}

void mode_three(int max_load, int interval, float handle_weight){
  int aim_value;
  aim_value = 0 + interval;
  tip_weight = read_tip();
  while (tip_weight < max_load){
    while (tip_weight < aim_value){
      turn_motor();
      Pause_stop();
      Display_output(handle_weight, tip_weight);
      tip_weight = read_tip();
    }
    save_to_array(interval_sum);
    aim_value = aim_value + interval;
    delay(1000);
  } 
}


void tare_one(){
  if (tare_1 == HIGH) {
    tip_read.tare();
  }
  if (tare_2 == HIGH) {
    handle_read.tare();
  }
}

void turn_motor(){
  digitalWrite(dirPin, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(stepPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(500);
  digitalWrite(stepPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(500);
}

float read_tip(){
  float weight;
  weight = (tip_read.get_units());
  return weight;
}
float read_handle(){
  float weight;
  weight = (handle_read.get_units());
  return weight;
}

void save_to_array(int interval_sum){
  data_storage_array[interval_sum][0] = interval_sum;
  data_storage_array[interval_sum][1] = tip_read.get_units();
  data_storage_array[interval_sum][2] = handle_read.get_units();
  interval_sum = interval_sum + 1;
}


int max_load_reading(){
  int KG_value;
  int g_value;
  int load_max;
  KG_value = analogRead(potentiometer1);
  g_value = analogRead(potentiometer2);
  KG_value = KG_value * 2;
  KG_value = KG_value/ 100;
  KG_value = round(KG_value);
  KG_value = KG_value* 100;
  g_value = g_value/ 10;
  g_value = round(g_value);
  if (g_value >= 100){
    g_value = 99;
  }
  load_max = KG_value + g_value;
  return load_max;
}

void Pause_stop(){
  if (digitalRead(stop1) == 1){
    delay(1000);
    while (digitalRead(start1) == 0){
      if (digitalRead(stop1) == 1){
        motor_unwind();
      }
      else{
        delay(100);
        lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
        lcd.print("Program Paused");
      }      
    }
    lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
    lcd.print("                    ");
  }
  
}

void motor_unwind(){
  tip_weight = read_tip();
  while (tip_weight < 100){
    digitalWrite(dirPin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(stepPin, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(500);
    digitalWrite(stepPin, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(500);
  }
  int count = 100;
  while (count > 0){
    digitalWrite(dirPin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(stepPin, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(500);
    digitalWrite(stepPin, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(500);
    count = count -1;
  }
}

void Display_mode_set_up(int mode){
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  if (mode == 1){
    lcd.print("Mode: Max           ");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("MLoad:");
    lcd.setCursor(12, 1);
    lcd.print("inti:---");
  }
  if (mode == 2){
    lcd.print("Mode: Incrimental    ");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("MLoad:");
    lcd.setCursor(12, 1);
    lcd.print("inti:   ");    
  }
  if (mode == 3){
    lcd.print("Mode: Automatic      ");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("MLoad:");
    lcd.setCursor(12, 1);
    lcd.print("inti:   ");   
  }
  lcd.setCursor(0, 3);
  lcd.print("Tp:");
  lcd.setCursor(9, 3);
  lcd.print("Hdle:");
}

void Display_value_set_up(int max_load, int interval, int mode){
  if (mode == 1){
    lcd.setCursor(6, 1);
    lcd.print("      ");
    lcd.setCursor(6, 1);
    lcd.print(max_load);
  }
  if (mode == 2 or mode == 3){
    
    lcd.setCursor(6, 1);
    lcd.print("      ");
    lcd.setCursor(6, 1);
    lcd.print(max_load);
    
    lcd.setCursor(17, 1);
    lcd.print("   ");
    lcd.setCursor(17, 1);
    lcd.print(interval);
  }
}

void Display_output(float handle_weight, float tip_weight){
  tip_weight = read_tip();
  handle_weight = read_handle();
  lcd.setCursor(3, 3);
  lcd.print("   ");
  lcd.setCursor(3, 3);
  lcd.print(tip_weight);
  lcd.setCursor(14, 3);
  lcd.print("    ");
  lcd.setCursor(14, 3);
  lcd.print(handle_weight);
}
```

Comment: What's in the function `get_units()`? In the `mode_*` subroutines, there are several `while` loops. Are you sure the conditions are being met for the loops to exit?